# al leer una seccion nueva de app.config devuelve null, como lo arreglo

Tags: .net, configuración

Este es mi problema, tengo un archivo `app.config` de la siguiente manera:

```
<configSections>
        <sectionGroup name ="GeneralTenantEmailSettings">
            <section name="TenantEmailSettings" type="DataApiService.Models.TenantEmailSettings, DataApiService.Models" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <TenantEmailSettings>
        <CcgSettingCcg SettingsId="520305DC-6E68-4FA3-B53B-18E25E0E21FF" TenantId="A0C55F11-516E-4F7C-9ECD-DEF7C47290B4" Frequency="168" StartDate="03/06/2020" RuleType="Default" To="Ccg" />
    </TenantEmailSettings>
```

Las clases asociadas son las siguientes:

```
namespace DataApiService.Models{
public class CcgSettings : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("SettingsId", IsRequired=true)]
        public Guid SettingsId 
        {
            get
            {
                return (Guid)this["SettingsId"];
            }
            set
            {
                value = (Guid)this["SettingsId"];
            }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("TenantId", DefaultValue = null, IsRequired = false)]
        public Guid? TenantId
        {
            get
            {
                return (Guid)this["TenantId"];
            }
            set
            {
                value = (Guid)this["TenantId"];
            }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("Frequency", DefaultValue = 0,IsRequired = true)]
        public int Frequency
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)this["Frequency"];
            }
            set
            {
                value = (int)this["Frequency"];
            }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("StartDate", IsRequired = true)]
        public DateTime StartDate
        {
            get
            {
                return (DateTime)this["StartDate"];
            }
            set
            {
                value = (DateTime)this["StartDate"];
            }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("RuleType", DefaultValue = "default", IsRequired = true)]
        public string RuleType
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)this["RuleType"];
            }
            set
            {
                value = (string)this["RuleType"];
            }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("To", IsRequired = true)]
        public string To
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)this["To"];
            }
            set
            {
                value = (string)this["To"];
            }
        }
    }

    public class TenantEmailSettings: ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("CcgSettings")]
        public CcgSettings CcgSettingsCcg
        {
            get
            {
                return (CcgSettings)this["CcgSettingCcg"];
            }
            set
            {
                value = (CcgSettings)this["CcgSettingCcg"];
            }
        }
    }
    public class GeneralTenantEmailSettings : ConfigurationSectionGroup
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("TenantEmailSettings")]

        public TenantEmailSettings TenantEmailSettings
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }}
```

y leo o lo intento de la siguiente manera:

```
 var t = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("TenantEmailSettings") as TenantEmailSettings; 
    var s = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("GeneralTenantSettings") as GeneralTenantEmailSettings;
    var c = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("CcgSettings") as CcgSettings;
    var b = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("CcgSettingsCcg") as CcgSettings;
```

Tengo dos problemas, bueno, uno pero está relacionado:
t, s, c, b son null, y no deberian serlo, y dos como leo?

ideas? el archivo tiene que ser .config pero no se si deberia indicar que es app.config y en tal caso como indicarlo, hasta ahora nada me ha funcionado

Comment: Si es null es porque el as no puede convertirlo. probaste var t = (TenantEmailSettings) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("TenantEmailSettings") para que te diga la excepcion?

Comment: No, no es null porque no pueda convertirlo, ese es uno de los problemas, que ConfigurationManager.GetSection("TenantEmailSettings") es null y según la documentación no puede serlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pues el problema no se pudo resolver tal cual. Lo que probé fue distintos paquetes Nuget, buena opción, pero no había ninguno para .net core 2.2 que se me adaptara.

El problema radicaba en que no puedo leer sin más en cualquier parte del programa, tengo que hacerlo en program.cs, fuera de ahí el context es distinto y por lo tanto devuelve null.

Solución: en vez de tratar app.config como un archivo xml de tipo config, lo traté como si fuera uno de texto normal y a partir de ahí parseando. Algo sencillo, que no da problemas sea cual sea la versión de .net